# How to find that Dehn invariant of a dodecahedron?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, platonic-solids

What is [the Dehn invariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_third_problem) of a regular dodecahedron with center (0,0,0), and radius 1?

Comment: Do you mean circumradius (radius of the sphere on which the vertices of the icosahedron live)?

Comment: Yes, I do mean that as a standard notion.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
D &= \sum_{e} \ell(e) \otimes \theta(e) \\
&= 30 \cdot \frac{4}{\sqrt{3} \left( 1 + \sqrt{5} \right)} \otimes \arccos \left( -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \right) \\
&\equiv 10\sqrt{3} \left( \sqrt{5} - 1 \right) \otimes \arccos \left( -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \right) \in \Bbb{R} \otimes_{\Bbb{Q}} \big(\Bbb{R}/(\Bbb{Q}\pi) \big)\end{align}
$$

Comment: Whoops!  I read *icosa*hedron.

Comment: I am editing it now.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Maple code $$with(geom3d):dodecahedron(gon, point(O, [0, 0, 0]), 1): $$ $$ sides(gon)$$ outputs $$2/3\,{\frac {\sqrt {3}}{1/2+1/2\,\sqrt {5}}} .$$

Comment: Could you explain the calculation of its dihedral angle (i. e. $\arccos \left(- \frac 1 {\sqrt{5}} \right)$) in detail?

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt{10}$ instead of $\sqrt{3}$ in the last line?

Comment: Your Maple output is equivalent to the expression that I used in the second line.

Comment: **Now** the coefficient is correct.  :-)

Comment: Because as yet neither $\frac{4}{\sqrt{3} \left( 1 + \sqrt{5} \right)} $  nor $ \arccos \left(- \frac 1 {\sqrt{5}} \right)$ are not explained, I cannot accept the answer.

Comment: You are looking for the geometric explanation that the length of a side of the dodecahedron inscribed in the unit sphere is $\frac{4}{\sqrt{3} \left( 1 + \sqrt{5} \right)}$ and that the dihedral angle is $\arccos \left( -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \right)$?

Comment: Yes, as it is written by me above.